# Accessing class variable with string name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class like this

```
$.fn.dimeBar = function(custom) {  
    var var1 = 'test1';  
    var var2 = 'test2';  
    if(sometest){  
        //how can i access var1 or var2 here by using string name of variables  
        //some thing like alert(this['var1']) --> should alert: 'test1'    
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$.fn.dimeBar = function(custom) {
  var options = {
    var1: 'test1',
    var2: 'test2'
  };

  if(sometest){
    var foo = 'var1';
    alert(options[foo]); // "test1"
  }

};
```

Alternatively, this may be a bit more inline with the [jQuery Plugin Development Pattern](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern)

```
(function($){
  $.fn.dimeBar = function(options){

    // defaults
    options = $.extend({
      var1: "default",
      var2: "hello world"
    }, options);

    // debug options
    $.each(options, function(key, value){
      console.log(key+' is set to'+value);    
    });

  };
})(jQuery);

$('#foo').dimeBar({var2: "hello kitty"});

// console output
// var1 is set to default
// var2 is set to hello kitty
```

Answer (score -3):

You would just use:
....

if (sometest)
{
  alert(var1);
}
....

Since you declared the vars before the if statement, they will be available from within it.

If you are worried about scope, if it's within an object, you would use:
alert(this.var1);

Comment: i want to access it with its string name 'var1'

Comment: +1 cause -4 seems too harsh here. it may not answer the question, but the answer is not day and night either to the question.